# Hi, marquee delay in non ie browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, marquee

Update: It seems it actually is delayed in internet explorer to.

Update: It seems to be starting sooner then it seemed, it's just that the text starts scrolling from the far right of the screen, and the text has a white colour and so does the background - and it's only supposed to show up in a yellow rectangle in the middle of the screen. Would anybody be able to help me with how to get this javacript marquee plugin from 'aamirafridi-jQuery.Marquee-304ed30 plugin' to start the text scrolling inside of that yellow box, and have the text scrolling be only inside of that yellow box that is in the middle of the screen?

I am using a marquee tag, to scroll news feeds from right to left, and because it's jittery, I tried implementing the 'aamirafridi-jQuery.Marquee-304ed30 plugin', from this [site](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples), the problem is that in IE it starts right away, but in firefox or google chrome it's delayed, I can decrease the `duration` param in the marquee function (see code below), to make it start sooner, but then the text scrolls too fast if I get it to show without delay. I've been trying to figure out a solution, but haven't managed to, does anyone have any suggestions? It would be much appreciated. Thankyou.

and I have this code:

```
function UR_Start() {
    UR_Nu = new Date;
UR_Indhold = showFilled(UR_Nu);
UR_Indhold = UR_Indhold.substring(0, UR_Indhold.indexOf("GMT"));
document.getElementById("ur").innerHTML = UR_Indhold;

    //document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML = window.rssContent;
$('.marquee').marquee({duration: 15000, delayBeforeStart: 0, direction: 'left'});
    initMarquee();
    load();
}
}

function load() {
    UR_Nu = new Date;
UR_Indhold = showFilled(UR_Nu);
UR_Indhold = UR_Indhold.substring(0, UR_Indhold.indexOf("GMT"));
document.getElementById("ur").innerHTML = UR_Indhold;
setTimeout("load()", 1000);
}

function initMarquee() {
    setTimeout("initMarquee()", 30000);
$('.marquee').marquee({duration: 15000, delayBeforeStart: 0, direction: 'left'});
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 5px 20px">

    <div class="well" style="background-color: <?php echo $layout_setting[2][value]; ?>; font-size:large; font-weight:bold;">

        <div id="marquee" class="marquee" class="marquee" style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 0 1em; overflow-style: marquee; marquee-style: scroll; marquee-loop: infinite; overflow-x: -webkit-marquee; width: 96%; -webkit-marquee-repetition: infinite; color: <?php echo $layout_setting[7][value] ?>" >

            <?php echo $rssContent; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: Actually, it seems that the delay happens in Internet Explorer too, as well as Firefox and Google Chrome.

Edit: I have updated the html, which now uses php to populate the marquee div, instead of using javascript to manipulate the html dom after page load.

Edit: I have updated the javascript code with the newest version of what I am attempting, with some of the code around it.

Comment: It also appears, the scrolling pauses for a split second every 7 seconds or so.

Comment: Could any of these problems be due to the fact that part of the webpage reloads every second to update a clock that shows second?

Comment: It at first sounds like a setInterval issue where the function does not fire until the first interval time has passed.  You may need to fire a single marquee at zero second interval, then it will pick up the others later

Comment: Firstly, changing the "duration" will change how long it takes to scroll. There is a "delayBeforeStart" which should control how long it takes to start. It seems that you already have this set to "0", so this is not the problem.

I suggest it could be something to do with when the pages load event is fired in different browsers.

Comment: This jsfiddle I just created based on your code doesn't have any delay in Chrome 32: http://jsfiddle.net/bZkBu/

Comment: How are you feeding the rssContent? If you're using Ajax, your delay could be associated with the data being loaded or added to the DOM.

Comment: Photodow: I just switched to using php, instead of ajax, but it's still has a delayed start.

Comment: I've updated the question with new details, and some things have changed a bit, like aparently Internet Explorer is still delayed a bit, and I am using php to populate the marquee div, and I am showing my latest javascript code with some of the code around it too.

Comment: With the duration parameter, it seems the higher the number, the slower the news feed ticker slides, and the longer it takes to start scrolling - and the lower the number, the faster it is, and it takes a shorter time. Right now, with using 15000 for duration, it takes about 4 seconds to start - and the speed isn't too bad. I am trying to get it to start at 0 seconds, and have the scroll speed not too fast.

Comment: ok - I changed the colour of the text in the marquee div, (which was white), and part of the problem is that it starts scrolling from the far right side of the screen, even though it is supposed to start at the right side of the yellow box in the middle of the screen, not at the far right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the plugin I made myself for this question.Tested in Firefox , Chrome & Opera.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZkBu/11/)

### *Plugin code used in fiddle*

```
/*Start of Plugin*/
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.marquee = function(params){
    params = $.extend( {direction : 'left',duration : '2000', delayStart : '0'}, params);
    var duration = parseInt(params.duration);
    var delay = parseInt(params.delayStart);

    var par = $(this);
    par.wrapInner('<span></span>');

    var parCh = par.children('span');
    var leftMargin = parCh.css('margin-left').replace('px','');
    var rightMargin = par.innerWidth()-leftMargin-parCh.width();

    function dirRight(){
        parCh.css({'margin-left':''+leftMargin+'px'});
        parCh.animate({
              'margin-left':''+rightMargin+'px'
            },duration,
              'linear',
            function(){
              dirRight();
            });
    }

    function dirLeft(){
        parCh.css({'margin-left':''+rightMargin+'px'});
        parCh.animate({
               'margin-left':''+leftMargin+'px'
            },duration,
              'linear',
            function(){
              dirLeft();
            });
    }

    if(params.direction == 'right'){
        setTimeout(function(){dirRight()},delay);
    }
    if(params.direction == 'left'){
        parCh.css({'margin-left':''+rightMargin+'px'});
        setTimeout(function(){dirLeft()},delay);
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        rightMargin = par.innerWidth()-leftMargin-parCh.width();
    });
};}( jQuery ));
/*End of Plugin*/

/*Call plugin*/
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //Set the direction of marquee
    'direction':'left',

    //delay the start of marquee
    'delayStart':'0',

    //Set the duration of marquee in millisecond
    'duration':'8000'
});
```

---

Try below fiddles and select whichever works for you as needed:

### 1. [Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/bZkBu/18/)

### 2. [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/bZkBu/17/)

### 3. [Fiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/bZkBu/19/)

**Note** : For the above three fiddles other than jQuery change I also changed the CSS for `.marquee` as below:

```
.marquee {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

**Hint** : If you want the marquee to start when the document is completely loaded write the plugin call within `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //Set the direction of marquee
    'direction':'left',

    //delay the start of marquee
    'delayStart':'0',

    //Set the duration of marquee in millisecond
    'duration':'8000'
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost solves my problem - but I want to get the text to start scrolling in from the far side of my yellow box div, instead of starting out showing completely in my yellow box div.

Comment: I've tried to make the text start scrolling in from the right part of my div, by changing the line in your dirRight function from `parCh.css({'margin-left' : '' + leftMargin + 'px'});` to `parCh.css({'margin-left' : '' + leftMargin + par.width() + 'px'});`, but that makes it start to far to the right. And it seems that when I use alert on par.width(), that gives 906, and par.innerWidth() or par.outWidth(), those are both 942. But from experimenting it seems that my div for the marquee is actually about 500, but I don't want to use a constant, because what if that changes. I need the real width

Comment: Ok i will post an updated fiddle.Check for an update

Comment: @user1296259 i added three new fiddles at the bottom of the answer.Check them

Comment: @user1296259 i am getting correct width of div on alerting.Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/bZkBu/20/ . BTW did you check my updated answer with three fiddles?

Comment: I checked out your plugins, but they didn't work, and I'm still having trouble getting the correct width, which I need to tweak your answer to solve my problem. Btw, this issue led me to creating a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611578/having-trouble-the-actual-width-of-some-html-in-javascript, if you can solve this new question for me, and that allows me to solve this problem, which I believe it will, I will reward you the answer and you will get the 50 points bounty.

Comment: Hey in the other question that you posted you removed the `.marquee` div which is present in my fiddles HTML . so you should use `.well` instead of `.marquee` in jQuery .Check my answer on your other question

Comment: The missing .marquee div in my other question was a mistake, I updated the question, and commented on your answer to your other question. Sorry about that.

Comment: I seemed to have got it working now, for some reason adding par.with() is working now.

Comment: Thankyou, for your help. I have rewarded you the 50 points bounty.

Comment: Good to see that finally you got it