# Having trouble the actual width of some html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, actualwidth

I am trying to use the javascript function width to get the width of a container, and use it to calculate where some scrolling text should start scrolling (I want it to scroll inside of a yellow box): [image]

Now, javascript code like this:

```
alert(yellowBox.width());
alert(yellowBox.innerWidth());
alert(yellowBox.outerWidth());
```

All show, 944, but I've determined the yellow box is actually a width of 500, but I don't want to use that value, because the width could change.

And I'm not sure how to get the actual width of the box. I've tried using `yellowBox.offsetWidth()`, and `yellowBox.clientWidth`, but they don't work, and the Web Developer, Web Console plugin for firefox tell me that "yellowBox.offsetWidth is not a function", and also "yellowBox.clientWidth is not a function.

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 5px 20px;">

  <div class="well" style="background-color: <?php echo $layout_setting[2][value]; ?>; font-size:large; font-weight:bold;">

    <div class="marquee" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; color: <?php echo $layout_setting[7][value] ?>; overflow: hidden; ">

      <?php echo $rssContent; ?>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

js plugin code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.marquee = function(params) {
        params = $.extend( {direction : 'left',duration : '2000', delayStart : '0'}, params);
        var duration = parseInt(params.duration);
        var delay = parseInt(params.delayStart);

        var par = $(this);

        alert(par.width());
        alert(par.innerWidth());
        alert(par.outerWidth());

        par.wrapInner('<span></span>');

        /*I get the same result for width both before and after the line that says `par.wrapInner('<span></span>');*/
        alert(par.width());
        alert(par.innerWidth());
        alert(par.outerWidth());

        var parCh = par.children('span');
        var leftMargin = parCh.css('margin-left').replace('px', '');
        var rightMargin = par.innerWidth() - leftMargin - parCh.width();

        function dirRight() {
            parCh.css({'margin-left' : '' + leftMargin + 'px'});
            //I've determined that `500` is about the width of the yellow box, by changing the line above to:
            //`parCh.css({'margin-left' : '' + leftMargin + 500 + 'px'});`
            //and seeing where that is the about the value it needs to be to have the left side of the text start out scrolling into the right side of the box
            //instead of having the left side of the scrolling text starting at the left side of the yellow box
            parCh.animate({'margin-left' : '' + rightMargin + 'px'}, duration, 'linear', function() { dirRight(); });
        }

        function dirLeft() {
            parCh.css({'margin-left' : '' + rightMargin + 'px'});
            parCh.animate({'margin-left' : '' + leftMargin + 'px'}, duration, 'linear', function() { dirLeft(); });
        }

        if (params.direction == 'right') setTimeout(function(){ dirRight() }, delay);

        if (params.direction == 'left') {
            parCh.css({'margin-left' : '' + rightMargin + 'px'});
            setTimeout(function(){ dirLeft() }, delay);
        }

        $(window).resize(function() { rightMargin = par.innerWidth() - leftMargin - parCh.width(); });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

and the function where I call the plugin:

```
function scrollMarquee() {
    setInterval("scrollMarquee()", 1000000);

$('.marquee').marquee({'direction' : 'right', 'delayStart' : '0', 'duration' : '1000000'});

}
```

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem? It's really hard to help with what you have, so far.

Comment: won't work in console because it does not know what yelowbox is. how did you determine the width is 500? also add some relative html/css so we know what's going on with this box

Comment: There's nothing in your html with the class of `marquee`.

Comment: I don't really understand how you're getting that the width is "really" 500px, but for one thing you don't need to keep calling `marquee` on your div. There's already a timeout inside of the `marquee` code.

Comment: Remove setInterval as commented by Colin

Comment: I removed the setInterval function

Comment: @user1296259 try calling the function at the end of the page instead of calling it before the HTML

Comment: And if my above comment doesnt work just add the source code generated by browser(View source code) to your question .

Comment: I am 100% sure that the Plugin code is not wrong becoz the width is alerted wrong.That means possible cause is your CSS or your order of writing JS is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be you are using `width()` `innerWidth()` and `outerWidth()` on wrong div or element for example

```
<div id="div1">
 <div id="div2" style="height:100px;width:300px;background-color:lightblue;"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Width of outer div: " + $("#div1").width()+"="+   $("#div1").innerWidth()+"="+ $("#div1").outerWidth());
    alert("Width of inner div: " + $("#div2").width()+"="+   $("#div2").innerWidth()+"="+ $("#div2").outerWidth());
});
</script>
```

will give you different values

Comment: I don't think I'm using the wrong div -- I've updated the question with more details showing my relative code and explaining how I know the box width is about 500.

Comment: this might be silly but is your div with `well` class getting width 944 from some where? cause then your marquee div will get that 100%

Comment: Yogesh I think at the time when the width is alerted the divs width is 100% and then its changed to smaller width when inline CSS executes

Comment: @Zword, I'm not sure, but the code is using bootstrap.css: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: it might be possible that when you wrap your marquee in span the width of parent is changed. what comes in my mind is try fixing width of parent element.

Comment: @user1296259 now all i can say is that you try to fix it yourself because i dont know what your CSS and other JS files have effect on your page.Also again its not Plugins issue.Its of width or `.marquee` .So try to fix that and it will work just like you want

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.marquee').marquee({'direction' : 'right', 'delayStart' : '0', 'duration' : '1000000'});
});
```

### ***OR***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.marquee').marquee({'direction' : 'right', 'delayStart' : '0', 'duration' : '1000000'});
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in the question, my html code does actually contain .marquee class, I've updated the question to show that.

Comment: Is your PHP content going beyond the screen width becoz whenever i m alerting the width its showing correct width

Comment: Well, if I do `alert(parCh.width())`, it shows `44168`, because the value of the $rssContent is a very long list of titles of different news stories, but that's not the value I'm using to try to get the width of the yellow box, I'm trying `par.width()`, `par.innerWidth()`, and `par.outerWidth()`, all which give a value of `944`, even though the correct width is about `500`.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your page?

Comment: I removed the setInterval, and I added a screenshot of webpage

Comment: I seemed to have got it working now, for some reason adding par.with() is working now.